# AWS send success notification when lambda works as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that alarms when the metric sees an "error" in the logs. My notification is setup using aws's new chatbot.

I'm trying to look for a way to send a success notification when my lambda executes without errors.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? What have you wrote so far?

Comment: How about adding some output at the very end of the Lambda function that it would only print on success. Then just create another alarm metric that triggers off that message in the logs?

Comment: @MarkB I thought of that, but wouldn't creating an alarm inidcate that there is a red flag? basically i wan't it to show up as green when i get the slack notification

Comment: +1 for adding code at the end of your lambda that sends a notification to the source of your choice, assuming the primary alarm the lambda creates has a separate destination from the one you're wishing to use as a success notification destination. It sounds like the more valuable thing here would be to track lambda `Errors` though, where you have a few more options from existing tooling in the Lambda console graphs as well as Lambda CloudWatch Metrics (Errors).

Comment: @edmamerto an "alarm" can mean whatever you want it to mean, in the context of your application. For example an auto-scaling group is always going to have one alarm that is active and one that is inactive for scaling up or down the group. I would think of the "alarm" as more like a "trigger" in this instance.

Comment: Also, as nmwalsh noted, there is an existing CloudWatch metric for Lambda errors, so you probably don't need to scan logs for that particular metric.